# How to avoid writing the same value in every row?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of lists and I want to assign to the first element of each list a value in order from 0 to 3. I wrote the following code:

```
var = [[-1] * 5] * 4
for i in range(4):
    var[i][0] = i+1
print(var)
```

The output is

> [[4,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [4,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [4,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [4,-1,-1,-1,-1]]

But it should be:

> [[1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [2,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [3,-1,-1,-1,-1],
>   [4,-1,-1,-1,-1]]

How do I do it?

Comment: When you crated `var`, you have a same list 4 times.  "The same" meaning, when you change one, you change them all.  It is like having a list in row 0, and then mirrors for the rest of the rows.

Comment: @James Alright, thanks! That was quite unexpected ...